# Passing 'this' pointer as LPARAM

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi, casting, compiler-errors

I have as class as follows:

```
#include <Windows.h>
class MyClass
{
   void A();
   static BOOL CALLBACK proc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam);
};

void MyClass::A()
{
   EnumChildWindows(GetDesktopWindow(), MyClass::proc, static_cast<LPARAM>(this));
}

BOOL CALLBACK MyClass::proc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
   // ...
   return TRUE;
}
```

When I attempt to compile this in Visual C++ 2010, I get the following compiler error:

error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'MyClass *const ' to 'LPARAM'
There is no context in which this conversion is possible

If I change the definition of `MyClass::A` as follows, then the compile succeeds:

```
void MyClass::A()
{
   EnumChildWindows(GetDesktopWindow(), MyClass::proc, (LPARAM)this);
}
```

What is the explanation for the error in the first example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use a `reinterpret_cast` not a `static_cast` to perform a cast to a completely unrelated type.  See this [When should static_cast, dynamic_cast, const_cast and reinterpret_cast be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used) for more details on the different types of C++ casts.

Answer (score 5):

`static_cast` is used to cast related types, such as `int` to `float`, and `double` to `float`, or conversions which need *too little* effort, such as invoking single-parameter constructor, or invoking a user-defined conversion function.

`LPARAM` and `this` are pretty much unrelated, so what you need is `reinterpret_cast`:

```
LPARAM lparam =  reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(this);
EnumChildWindows(GetDesktopWindow(), MyClass::proc, lparam);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you know, the this pointer is **const** and the static_cast operator cannot cast away the **const**, **volatile**, or **__unaligned** attributes. Take a look at [this link on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c36yw7x9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).